# How to not reset Shiny dateRange when changing tab

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following simple data in a csv named `sampledata.csv`, which I'm using in a `shinydashboard` app.

```
date    category
1/1/2001    1M
1/2/2001    1M
1/3/2001    1M
1/4/2001    1M
1/5/2001    1M
1/1/2002    2M
1/2/2002    2M
1/3/2002    2M
1/4/2002    2M
1/5/2002    2M
```

I have the following `shinydashboard` code in an `app.R` file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id='tab',
      menuItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
      menuItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2')
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='tab1',
        uiOutput('daterange')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab2',
        verbatimTextOutput('range')
      )
    )
  )
)

sample <- read.csv('sampledata.csv')
sample$date <- as.Date(sample$date, '%m/%d/%Y')

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Observe which tab is selected
  observe({
    print(input$tab)
  })

  subdata <- reactive({
    #Subset to include only sample$category=='1M' when any tab is selected
    if(input$tab=="tab1" | input$tab=="tab2"){
      sample <- sample[which(sample$category=='1M'),]
    }
    return(sample)
  })

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    #Set daterange to go from min to max of subdata()
    dateRangeInput(inputId='daterange', 
      label='Select Period', 
      min=min(subdata()$date), max=max(subdata()$date)
    )
  })

  output$range <- renderPrint(input$daterange)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problem is when using the app, if I change from `tab1` to `tab2`, `daterange` gets reset. So if on `tab1` I change the start or end date and then click on `tab2`, it no longer keeps my selected dates. In the code above I know the `if` statement in `subdata` seems redundant, and if I get rid of it my problem goes away. But in reality I have a more complex app and subdata will change depending on which tab has been selected. Is there a way to keep the `if` statement but not have `daterange` reset when changing tabs?

Answer (score 0):

move `uiOutput('daterange')` to the  `sidebarMenu`

```
sidebarMenu(id='tab',
      menuItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
      menuItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2'),
      uiOutput('daterange')
    )
```

or you can use isolate

```
  output$range <- renderPrint(  isolate({input$daterange })  )
```

Comment: That fixes the issue but then `daterange` is on the sidebar. I want to keep it in the body.

Comment: with the `isolate`  it should work i edited my first post

Comment: It's still not working. I'm getting the same problem with `isolate`.